# Wordpress custom post categories and subcategories on category.php

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I've custom post "products" with standart categories and subcategories. Now I need to display a list of products on category page, that current category contains.

If category don't have subcategories I need to display this:

```
<ul class="cat-arc-links">
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 3</a></li>
......
</ul>
```

And if category contains sub categories display this:

```
<span class="subhead-title">Subcat 1</span>
<ul class="cat-arc-links">
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 3</a></li>
......
</ul>

<span class="subhead-title">Subcat 2</span>
<ul class="cat-arc-links">
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-link">Product 3</a></li>
......
</ul>
```

How can I modyfy my `categories.php` to make my case done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all! Here is my solution which worknig well

```
<?php 

$cat = get_query_var('cat');

$categories = get_categories('parent='.$cat.''); 

if(isset($categories) && !empty($categories)){ 

    foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>

        <span class="subhead-title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>

        <?php $prods = new WP_query(); $prods->query('post_type=products&cat=' . $category->cat_ID . ''); ?>
            <?php if($prods->have_posts()) { ?> <ul class="cat-arc-links"> <?php while ($prods->have_posts()) { $prods->the_post(); ?>

                 <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>


             <?php } ?> </ul> <?php } ?>

<?php }

}
else 
{
    global $query_string; // basic query parameters
    query_posts( $query_string.'&post_type=products'); // basic query + self parameters 

    if( have_posts() ) { ?> <ul class="cat-arc-links"> <?php  while( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php } /* end of while */  wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
        <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
    </div>

<?php
    } 
    else 
        echo "<h2>No entries.</h2>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the primary category (the one that's loaded to the categories.php template), you can use the function `get_term_children()` to get all of its children.

It will return false or an empty array if it doesn't have children. In the example below, I assumed that your product's taxonomy is name `products_categories`.

```
<?php 
    $term = <youPrimaryTerm>;
    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id, 'products_categories');

    if(!empty($term_children)):
        foreach($term_children as $child):
            // Magic for subcategories template
        endforeach;
    else:
        // Magic in case there is no subcategories
    endif;
?>
```

In each scenario, you will then have to create a new WP_Query using the `$child->term_id` or the  `$term->term_id`.

Note that, if a product is available in two subcategories, it will be displayed twice on the same page.

See Codex for reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children

**EDIT**

To load the current category (when in the `category.php` template) as to replace the `<yourPtrimaryTerm>` from my first example, you should be able to use this snippet:

```
<?php
    $termTitle = single_cat_title( '', false );
    $termId = get_cat_ID($termTitle);
    $term = get_term($termId, 'products_categories');
?>
```

Comment: What I need to write in `$term = <youPrimaryTerm>;` if I need do this stuff with all terms (categories and subcategories) that I have?

Comment: I just added a little snippet that should allow you to complete the code above. Don't hesitate if you need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it should work and sure you can edit the query arguments to fit your needs. copy&past code with proper `html` tags and it should work. Check and if it worked i will try to make it more cleaner.

```
    <?php
        $this_category = get_category($cat);
        $cats=get_categories(array('hide_empty' => '0', 'parent'=>$this_category ->cat_ID,'order'=> 'ASC','depth'=> '1'));

        if(!empty($cats)){
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                $newargs = array(
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'field' => 'name',
                                'terms' => $cat->name,
                                        )
                             )
                          );
                echo'<div>';
                echo '<span class="subhead-title">'.$cat->name.'</span>';
                $nopostsparent= new wp_query( $newargs );
                if ($nopostsparent->have_posts()) {
                    echo '<ul class="cat-arc-links">';
                while ($nopostsparent->have_posts() ){
                    $nopostsparent->the_post();
                       echo'<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" class="product-link">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                }
                wp_reset_query();
                echo '</ul></div>';
             }
            }
        }else{
        $newargs = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $this_category->name,
                    )
                  )
            );
            $nopostsparent= new wp_query( $newargs );
            if ($nopostsparent->have_posts()) {
              echo '<ul class="cat-arc-links">';
            while ($nopostsparent->have_posts() ){
             $nopostsparent->the_post();
             echo'<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" class="product-link">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
            }
            wp_reset_query();
                echo '</ul></div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some ideas for your requirement. Check below code... don't forgot to update taxonomy and custom post type bellow code .

```
$parent= get_queried_object()->term_id;
$taxonomy = get_categories('child_of='.$parent. '&hide_empty=0&echo=0&taxonomy=custom_taxonomy');

if(count($taxonomy) > 0){

     foreach ( $taxonomy as $row ) { 
        echo '<span>'.$row->name.'</span>';
        if(count($child)==$i){
            echo '<ul class="cat-arc-links">';
            $args=array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post','posts_per_page'=>1,'tax_query'  => array( array('taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy','terms' =>$row->term_id, 'field' => 'id' )) );
            $second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ($second_query->have_posts()) :
                    while ($second_query->have_posts()) : $second_query->the_post();
                        echo ' <li><a href="'.get_permalink(get_the_ID()).'" class="product-link">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                    endwhile; 
                endif; wp_reset_query();
            echo '</ul>';       
        }
     }

}else{
    echo '<ul class="cat-arc-links">';
    $args=array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post','posts_per_page'=>1,'tax_query'  => array( array('taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy','terms' =>get_queried_object()->term_id, 'field' => 'id' )) );
    $second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ($second_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($second_query->have_posts()) : $second_query->the_post();
                echo ' <li><a href="'.get_permalink(get_the_ID()).'" class="product-link">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
            endwhile; 
        endif; wp_reset_query();
    echo '</ul>';       

}
```